# Java: Trouble calling another class

Tags: java

I am just beginning in Java and I am having a peculiar problem that I just cant seem to get to the root of. I have 2 programs and one is taking data from a text file and then calling it into a class to do some calculations and finally putting the output into another text document.

Everything works except this part here:

```
public class Paycheck
{
//Constants for the private class
private final String EMPLOYEE_NAME;           //Employee name          
private final String SOC_SEC_NUM;             //Employee Social Security Number
private final double WAGE_RATE;               //Employee wage
private final double TAX_RATE;                //Employee tax withheld 
private final double HOURS_WORKED;            //Employee's hours of work

//Variables for the private class
private double grossPay;                      //Employee Gross Pay
private double taxWithheld;                   //Employee Tax Withheld
private double netPay;                        //Employee Net Pay





//This is the constructor. It is called whenever an instance of the class is created
public Paycheck (String name, String ssn, double wage, double tax, double hours)
{
    EMPLOYEE_NAME = name;  //Instance employee name
    SOC_SEC_NUM = ssn;    //Instance employee SSN
    WAGE_RATE = wage;      //Instance employee wage rate
    TAX_RATE = tax;        //Instance employee tax rate
    HOURS_WORKED = hours;  //Instance employee hours worked
}

//This calculates the variables in the paycheck class
public void calcWages()
{
    grossPay = WAGE_RATE * HOURS_WORKED;    //Calculates Gross Pay
    taxWithheld = grossPay * TAX_RATE;      //Calculates Taxes Withheld
    netPay = grossPay - taxWithheld;        //Calculates net pay

}




//Returns the Paycheck objects Employee Name
public String getEmployeeName()
{
    return EMPLOYEE_NAME;
}

//Returns the employee SSN of the Paycheck object
public String getSocSecNum()
{
    return SOC_SEC_NUM;
}

//Reeturns a Paycheck object's employee Wage Rate
public double getWageRate()
{
    return WAGE_RATE;
}

//Returns a Paycheck object's employee tax rate
public double getTaxRate()
{
    return TAX_RATE;
}

//Returns an Paycheck object's employee hours worked
public double getHoursWorked()
{
    return HOURS_WORKED;
}

//Returns a Paycheck object's gross pay
public double getGrossPay()
{
    return grossPay;
}

//Returns a Paycheck object's Taxes Withheld
public double getTaxWithheld()
{
    return taxWithheld;
}

//Returns a paycheck object't net pay 
public double getNetPay()
{
    return netPay;
}
```

The calcWages() does the necessary calculations and below this are a series of get statements to call them. However, my output does not return any values for the calcWages() arguments.

I added the getters here and my other program is grabbing them. However the final output on my other program is coming up as 0.

Where am I going wrong here?

This is the part of the main method that is calling them

```
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException //Throws clause
{
    //Declare constants
    final String INPUT_FILE = "Employee.txt";         //Input text file containing Employee information
    final String OUTPUT_FILE= "PayrollHistory.txt";   //Output text file that will receive the data

    //Declare Variables
    String payPeriodDate;       //Ending date of the pay period
    String employeeName;        //Employee Name in text file
    String employeeSocSecNum;   //Employee SSN in text file
    double employeeHours;       //Employee hours worked
    double employeeTax;         //Employee Tax rate 
    double employeeWage;        //Employee Wage rate
    double totalGrossPay;       //Total employee Gross for pay period
    double totalTaxWithheld;    //Total Tax Withheld for pay period
    double totalNetPay;         //Total Net Payroll for pay period
    String input;               //String input for double conversion in JoptionPane

    DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat ("#0.00"); // Decimal Format to put money in the right format(USD)

    //This ensures that the input file actually exists in the program folder 
    //And exits the program if it does not, along with the prompt.
    File file = new File(INPUT_FILE);
  if (!file.exists())
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The " + INPUT_FILE + " file cannot be found." +
                        "Program terminated.");
     System.exit(0);
  }


    // Create Scanner object to enable reading data from input file
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

  // Create FileWriter and PrintWriter objects to enable
  // writing (appending not overwriting) data to text file
  FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(OUTPUT_FILE, true);
  PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);

    //Initialize accumulator values
  totalGrossPay = 0.0;
    totalTaxWithheld = 0.0;
    totalNetPay = 0.0;

    //Get the pay period for the employee
    payPeriodDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter pay period ending date (mm/dd/yyyy):");
    outputFile.println("PAY PERIOD ENDING DATE: " + payPeriodDate);          //Inputs pay period date into the text file
    outputFile.println(); // Blank line
    outputFile.println(); // Blank line


    while (inputFile.hasNext()) // This will look through the input file and get the necessary variable input
  {
     // Read employee Name from Input File
     employeeName = inputFile.nextLine();
     // Read employee SSN from input file
     employeeSocSecNum = inputFile.nextLine();
     // Read employee Wage Rate from input file
        //Parses it into a double type
     input = inputFile.nextLine();
     employeeWage = Double.parseDouble(input);
        //Read employee tax rate from input file
        //Parses it into a double type
        input = inputFile.nextLine();
        employeeTax = Double.parseDouble(input);


        //Get number of hours worked
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Employee Name: " + employeeName +
                                                        "\nEnter number of hours worked:");
        employeeHours = Double.parseDouble(input);

        //This call the paycheck class to create a new Paycheck Object
        Paycheck employee = new Paycheck (employeeName, employeeSocSecNum, employeeWage, employeeTax, employeeHours);

        // Call Paycheck class methods into the output file
     outputFile.println("Employee Name: " + employeeName);                              //Employee Name
     outputFile.println("SSN: " + employeeSocSecNum);                                   //Employee SSN
     outputFile.println("Hours Worked: " + employeeHours);                              //Employee Hours Worked
     outputFile.println("Wage Rate: " +  money.format(employeeWage));                   //Employee Wage Rate
        outputFile.println("Gross Pay: " +  money.format(employee.getGrossPay()));         //Employee Gross Pay
        outputFile.println("Tax Rate: " +  money.format(employeeTax));                     //Employee Tax Rate
        outputFile.println("Tax Withheld: " +  money.format(employee.getTaxWithheld()));   //Employee Tax Withheld
        outputFile.println("Net Pay: " + employee.getNetPay());                            //Employee Net Pay
     outputFile.println(); // Blank line
```

Comment: post code where you are calling calcWages and where you are printing the output. You likely are referencing the wrong object

Comment: Hi, can show the code that is actually calling this class, that isnt working? What output are you refering to?

Comment: Where are you actually *calling* your getters? You didn't add that. We're looking for a main method here.

Comment: I added the main method portion as well as the getters.

Comment: Still incomplete. How are you initializing employee?

Comment: Paycheck employee = new Paycheck (employeeName, employeeSocSecNum, employeeWage, employeeTax, employeeHours);

Comment: 1. put that in the question, 2. ok, yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to be actually *calling* `calcWages()` before calling your getters, so  `grossPay, taxWithheld, and netPay` are still going to be 0, as that's Java's default value for uninitialized numbers.

You need to call `employee.calcWages()` before referencing those values for them to change.

Comment: To clarify a little for the OP, you need to actually _call_ `calcWages()` e.g., right after you create a new Paycheck, but before your print statements you need `employee.calcWages();`   --Also don't forget to accept @Colleen 's answer

Comment: didn't want to "steal" your answer...just seemed like he was missing the point a little :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because `calcWages()` is declared **void** (`public void calcWages()`), meaning it is not supposed to return any value but just complete a series of steps (calc payroll particulars in this example).  After calling it, just proceed to reference the instance variables it processed.

Comment: Yes, I know that but the get statement below should be able to actually get me the value yes?

Comment: where do you call calcWages? maybe what you're not getting is the function won't DO anything unless you call it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your variables as `final`, meaning they can only be assigned once.

Comment: I don't understand. Where do I need to initialize?

Comment: @Colleen, looks like your answer is correct. The code he posted originally was somewhat incomplete.

Comment: On a side note, the way you're looping through the input file isn't correct - you should only call `nextLine()` once inside the loop body. Example:
`while (input.hasNext()) { line = input.nextLine(); }`